# Phpmyadmin and column level privileges

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using column level privileges on some tables, but theese tables are unusable with phpmyadmin browse feature, because he execute SELECT * ... query, and this occurs SELECT command denied to user ... error. How can i solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I've opened a ticket about this at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11922 but I'm not sure how feasible it is to fix. You can follow the discussion there for more information.